# ValidateProperties code

Tags: c#, validation, mvvm, mvvmcross

Hi all i am using mvvmcross and portable class libraries , so i cannot use prism or componentmodel data annotations, to validate my classes. basically i have a modelbase that all my models inherit from.

My validate code below is horribly broken, basically im looking for the code that data annotations uses to iterate thru all the properties on my class that is inheriting the base class ,

i have written various attributes that are there own validators inheriting from "validatorBase" which inherits from attribute. i just cannot for the life of me figure out thecode that says ... ok im a class im going to go through all the properties in me that have an attribute of type ValidatorBase and run the validator. my code for these are at the bottom

```
public class ModelBase
{

    private Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> _errors;
    public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> Errors
    {
        get
        {
            return _errors;
        }

    }

    protected  virtual bool Validate()
    {
        var propertiesWithChangedErrors = new List<string>();

        // Get all the properties decorated with the ValidationAttribute attribute.
        var propertiesToValidate = this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties()
                                                    .Where(c => c.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidatorBase)).Any());

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertiesToValidate)
        {
            var propertyErrors = new List<string>();
            TryValidateProperty(propertyInfo, propertyErrors);

            // If the errors have changed, save the property name to notify the update at the end of this method.
            bool errorsChanged = SetPropertyErrors(propertyInfo.Name, propertyErrors);
            if (errorsChanged && !propertiesWithChangedErrors.Contains(propertyInfo.Name))
            {
                propertiesWithChangedErrors.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
            }
        }

        // Notify each property whose set of errors has changed since the last validation.  
        foreach (string propertyName in propertiesWithChangedErrors)
        {
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
            OnPropertyChanged(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Item[{0}]", propertyName));
        }

        return _errors.Values.Count == 0;

    }
}
```

here is my validator

```
public class BooleanRequired : ValidatorBase
{
    public override bool Validate(object value)
    {

        bool retVal = true;
        retVal = value != null && (bool)value == true;
        var t = this.ErrorMessage;
        if (!retVal)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Accept is Required";
        }
        return retVal;
         }
}
```

and here is an example of its usage

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Amount")]
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { _amount = value;  }//SetProperty(ref _amount, value); }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `IDataErrorInfo`?

Comment: The main reason we dont want to do that , is we are currently doing a POC in Xamarin, and are wanting to reuse our existing validations on a very large application. if we change to use the errordatainfo, then we will have to redo the validatoin for all the applications , we are also very sure that microsoft will someday soon reinclude the use data annotations .. and will affect the success of our POC